# OLS - Correlation of Residuals Over Longer Time Frames

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares

I'm running a standard financial time series analysis - calculating multi-variate OLS against 6 different factors on a monthly returns oriented time series. The time series seem to be pretty well behaved, with 1 or 2 lags of autocorrelation and some skewness.

In looking at the monthly residuals (e.g. excess returns / alphas), they are effectively uncorrelated with one of the independent factors, as would be expected from an OLS.

[image]

Nothing stands out when looking at the residual vs. fitted value plot either - no heteroscedasticity.

However, when looking at rolling 12M returns of the residuals and the independent factors, correlation increases significantly (90%).

[image]

What concept am I missing here? Is this just spurious correlation? Is there an underlying hidden variable that I need to incorporate? Is there co-integration going on? Is a natural effect of incorporating rolling windows to increase correlation? What should I be googling?

Comment: Also posted on Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/ols-correlation-of-residuals-over-longer-time-frames).

Comment: Closed there for this reason